# vue.js unable to post using axios

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vue.js, axios

Vue.js code

```
methods:{
update(){
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:56304/api/BrandVendor/Post',
    data: {
        test: "testing123",
    }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      debugger
        console.log(error);
    });

}
},
```

asp.net web api

```
public class BrandVendorController : ApiController
{
    private BrandVendorRepository brandVendorRepository;
    public BrandVendorController()
    {
        this.brandVendorRepository = new BrandVendorRepository();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(string test)
    {
        var text = test;

        string textReturn = "Return from API";

        return textReturn;
    }
}
```

It gives me 404, can i know where did i do wrong?

> POST http://localhost:56304/api/BrandVendor/Post 404 (Not Found)
>   App.vue?d27e:44 Error: Request failed with status code 404
>       at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
>       at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:77:7)

Its really frustrating.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Somehow i am able to get it work by adding the [FromBody], but then axios seems to send empty object.
I am very new to both web api and vue js

```
public class BrandVendorController : ApiController
{
    private BrandVendorRepository brandVendorRepository;
    public BrandVendorController()
    {
        this.brandVendorRepository = new BrandVendorRepository();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string test)
    {
        var text = test;

        string textReturn = "Return from API";

        return textReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is a server code configuration problem. Have you tried manually defining your path on your Post method? For example: `[HttpPost("/api/Brandvendor/Post")]`

Comment: @jostrander but i am able to call it using Postman
POST "http://localhost:56304/api/BrandVendor/Post?test=asdasd"

Comment: Is `test=asdasd` required in order for it to not show a 404 page? Then you may need to change your data in axios to a params list instead. data is passed in via body, params are passed in via URL.